# Use a non-GDB SDO_GEOMETRY table in a map service?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, map-service, sdo-geometry

I have a table with an SDO_GEOMETRY column (points) in an external system.

- The external system is an Oracle 12c database; it is not a geodatabase.

---

I want to serve up the SDO_GEOMETRY table to a map service/ArcGIS Server 10.7.1.

- I want to display & query the layer in a web map which is based on a map service. I do not need to edit features.

Is it possible to do this, even though the table is not registered with a geodatabase?

Comment: Do some research on Query Layers. I've only created a quarter-million layers out of non-geodatabase spatial tables in the past few years. There are optimization challenges at times, but that's mostly scale dependency management.

Comment: Using Query Layers is still the answer.

Comment: @Vince Have you ever tried something like this? [Set up an Oracle DBMS spatial table for editing via a feature service](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012057)

Comment: I haven't, and if you do not need to edit features, it's unclear why you would need to either.  If the requirements have changed, it might be worth a new question; if you want to edit this one, I'll delete my QL comments.